# Exclusive logical sum (XOR)

Tags: xor

I have this question :

[image: xor]

The answer is D, because they explain :

> (n XOR 1111 1111) will reverse 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 , then plus the
>   result with 1, we have two's complement

But as i understand, the XOR operation is :

> a logical operation that outputs true whenever both inputs differ

example :

```
1011 XOR 1000 = 0011
```

So how can (**n** XOR 1111 1111) is inverted **n** (one's complement) ??

Comment: why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @KeithNicholas haha, oh my god, the problem is so simple. i've never  tried it, i just kept thinking it can't be , oh my god, this is a very big lesson i learned to day. Your comment is good as answer to me, just put in in the answer field and i will mark it, thanks very much !!

Comment: my comment isn't an answer, its just what you need to do to learn it properly.  There are answers below that are technically correct.  But in general, you should perform bitwise operations yourself and really get a good feel for them.  Makes a big difference later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using all 1s in the second operand,

- If 1st operand has `1`, then you get `1 XOR 1 = 0` (same inputs so `false`)
- If 1st operand has `0`, then you get `0 XOR 1 = 1` (different inputs so `true`)

So for the 1st operand, `1` becomes `0`, and `0` becomes `1`. Thus the number is bit-reversed.

So in your example,

```
1011 XOR 1111 = 0100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n xor 1 = not n
```

Because

If n is 1 then it does not differ from 1 so the output is 0

If n is 0 then it does differ from 1 so the output is 1